# Android media player - rewind on MPEG-TS file which is being updated

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have an Android TV application which works with MPEG-TS files (on Amlogic box).

We have 1-hour length files, like there are files 13.mpeg, 14.mpeg...24.mpeg etc (one file for each hour).

I have a problem when rewinding a file of current hour, like if its 12:50 now, the file 12.mpeg is being updated constantly with new data, but if I rewind to 12:48 from 12:50, player will only go up till 12:50 and then it will think that file has been completed and go to `OnCompletionListener`, when in reality file is already updated till 12:52. So the player doesn't detect updated data, only the data that was recorded till the point I requested seek.

I suspected Content-Length HTTP header, but it is being updated with each response so technichally the player should know about new content. It is either ignoring the info and only works according to first response or something else I cannot understand.

Here is the snippet I use for simple rewind:

```
MainActivity.mediaPlayer.reset();
MainActivity.mediaPlayer.setDataSource(newPlayUrl);
MainActivity.mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

MainActivity.mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        MainActivity.mediaPlayer.start();
        MainActivity.mediaPlayer.seekTo(ts * 1000);
        paused = false;
    }
});
```

My question is: is there a way I can tell the player to request an updated file in background, so the rewind can work properly?

Comment: Honestly, I can't help you. But...have you alredy tried [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer)? It should support HLS  better then the standard MediaPlayer (and...use ExoPlayer version 2)

Comment: Hi, I can't use ExoPlayer since I have to use media player provided by Amlogic, which is based on native Android MediaPlayer

Comment: In this case you need to customize existing media player provided by Amlogic with background updating code.

Comment: The player is 90% based on native android player, isn't there some source from where I can get the idea about how to do that? Or I do I have to do it from 0?

Comment: While seeking, Have you tried doing:  Pause,  seek, resume in your existing code?

Comment: Also try, setOnSeekCompleteListener instead of OnCompletionListener and setOnBufferingUpdateListener